# How do I toggle between two jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have my dropdown menu script bellow:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseover', openSubMenu);
  $('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseout', closeSubMenu);
  function openSubMenu() {            
    $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');            
  };                

  function closeSubMenu() {            
    $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden');         
  };                       
});
```

It shows dropdown menu when the mouse gets over. I want to implement this on my responsive theme, so it has to be click. I tried following code:

```
    $('.myMenu > li').toggle(openSubmenu, closeSubmenu);
```

Instead of 2 lines of `.bind` . But it wouldn't work, neither did `.click` method helped. So how do I put two states/functions into `.toggle` method ?

Comment: You can just bind both events using one 'bind' statement, and inside the bound function, put your logic that detects the state of the element (or use '.toggleClass()' like in my answer below :-)

Answer (score 0):

If thats the only thing that occurs on the click, you can use one click handler, and toggle a CSS class instead:

```
 $('.myMenu > li').bind('click', function(e) {$(this).toggleClass('hidden')});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using mouse events you can simply use [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) also use [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) instead of css hidden and don't worry it's cross-browser.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myMenu').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).find('ul').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: There is some really bad advice here. jQuery show() and hide() helper methods are extremely inefficient and should not be used over toggling a class or changing the css dynamically. See https://twitter.com/paul_irish/status/564443848613847040

Answer (score 0):

Use "on" to add event listeners for both mouseover and click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.myMenu > li').on('mouseover click', openSubMenu);
    $('.myMenu > li').on('mouseout', closeSubMenu);

    function openSubMenu() {        
        $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'visible');            
    };                
    function closeSubMenu() {              
        $(this).find('ul').css('visibility', 'hidden');         
    };                       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create one handler for the class toggling, and bind it to all of the desired events like so:

**CSS**

```
li.hidden ul {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var toggleHiddenClass = function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
};
$('.myMenu > li').bind('mouseover mouseout click', toggleHiddenClass);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.toggle();` method accepts a boolean value `true` to show and `false` to hide.

So you can check the event type if event type is `mouseover` then show the hidden `ul` otherwise on `mouseout` hide it.

Also as a side note you can use `.on()` which is now standards of event binding in jquery.

Try this:

```
$('.myMenu > li').on('mouseover mouseout', function(e){
    $(this).find('ul').toggle(e.type === "mouseover");
});
```

```js
$('ul > li').on('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
  $(this).find('ul').toggle(e.type === "mouseover");
});
```

```css
ul ul {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>menu
    <ul>
      <li>sub menu</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```